# Pandas - how to sort rows of a column, using a dictionary with indexes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have to sort the values/rows of a column of a Dataframe according to a dictionary, which contains each value of the dataframe and its row index, but sorted differently.

```
howToSortDict = {'Brazil': 2, 'Russia': 0, 'China': 1} # row value and its index

myDict = {
    "countries": ["Brazil", "Russia", "China"],
    "amount": [1000, 2000, 3000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(myDict)
```

How they are sorted:

```
     countries  amount
0    Brazil     1000
1    Russia     2000
2    China      3000
```

How I need them to be sorted (as a dataframe):

```
    countries   amount
0   Russia      2000
1   China       3000
2   Brazil      1000
```

Any ideas of how to achieve this without looping over each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two steps:

First use `map` to create a new column with the values associated with the countries

```
df['country_value'] = df.countries.map(howToSortDict)
```

Then `sort` and `drop` the new column

```
df.sort_values('country_value').drop('country_value',axis=1)

#    countries   amount
#1   Russia      2000
#2   China       3000
#0   Brazil      1000
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[df.countries.map(howToSortDict).argsort()]
  countries  amount
1    Russia    2000
2     China    3000
0    Brazil    1000
```